# How to allow user to input file names in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script, rar

I've got this script I called it "r1":

```
for f in "$@"
do
fpath=`dirname "$f"`
file=`basename "$f"`
arc=$fpath"/"$file".rar"
rar a -v1024000 -r -m0 -ep1 -o- "$arc" "$f"
done
```

It works well but I am not able to change archive name
I wish I could do this so the outcome of:

> r1 Myphoto Photos/

whould be an archive called Myphoto.rar containing Photos/ dir

How should I modify the script?

I think that this line:

```
file=`basename "$f"`
```

should be different, so it will allow me to choose archive name on my own

Answer (score 0):

The following script will do exactly what you are asking for.

```
 #!/bin/sh

 if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]
    then
    echo " Two arguments needed, a file name for the rar file "
    echo " and a directory/file name to be compressed. "
    echo " Both can be relative or absolute addresses "
    exit 1
 fi

 if [ -e $1.rar ] 
    then
    echo " File $1.rar already exists. Quitting "
    exit 2
 fi

 if [ ! -d $2 -a ! -e $2 ]
    then
    echo " $2 is not a directory/file to be compressed. Quitting "
    exit 3
 fi

 file=$1
 dir=$2
 rar a -v1024000 -r -m0 -ep1 "$file".rar  $dir
 exit
```

I have added an absolute minimum of error checking, and a line reminding you that you may use this script to compress both files and folders.

Comment: Not working with directory with long names and spaces

Comment: @John Not true: the problem is how you pass arguments from the command line. If you have a directory called "a b" (without apostrophes), you must issue the command as follows: r1 filename a\ b     It will work then.